# How to map routes to controllers in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, model-view-controller, routes, sinatra

I'd like to create a simple experimental MVC framework using Sinatra.

I'd like to define resources by name `"pages"` for example should resolve to:

```
/pages (index)
/pages/new
/pages/:id/show (show)
```

as WELL as map to `app/controllers/PagesController.rb` with corresponding `get('/')` to be responsible for the index, `post('/pages/create')` be responsible for creation, etc.

Trouble is even after reading the official documentation I'm terribly confused. I imagine I need to use non-classic Sinatra model for this, but could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: *with corresponding `get('/')`*, don't you mean `get('/pages')`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Essentially how do I mimic what Rails does with controllers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want what I think you're wanting, I do this all the time. Initially for this scheme I used the travis-api source as a reference, but essentially what you want to do is extend Sinatra::Base in a "controller" class and then mount up your individual Sinatra "controllers" in rack, something like this:

```
module Endpoint
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      set(:prefix) { "/" << name[/[^:]+$/].downcase }
    end
  end
end

class Users < Sinatra::Base
  include Endpoint

  get '/' do
    #logic here
  end

  get '/:id' do
    #logic here
  end

  post '/' do
    #logic here
  end

  patch '/:id' do
    #logic here
  end
end

class Posts < Sinatra::Base
  include Endpoint

  post '/' do
    #logic here
  end
end
```

and then something like this:

```
class App
  require "lib/endpoints/users"
  require "lib/endpoints/posts"

  attr_reader :app

  def initialize
    @app = Rack::Builder.app do
      [Users, Posts].each do |e|
        map(e.prefix) { run(e.new) }
      end
    end
  end

  def call(env)
    app.call(env)
  end
end
```

You can adjust this to whatever you need, but the idea is the same, you separate your app into composable Sinatra applications that each have a prefix that they are mounted under using Rack. This particular example will give you routes for:

get '/users'

get '/users/:id'

post '/users'

patch '/users/:id'

get '/posts'

Comment: Just fyi, you would run this app by calling `run App.new`

Comment: Could you please explain where the `self.included(base)` is coming from and what it does exactly? Thank you

Comment: The `self.included(base)` logic is a (perhaps overly complex) way for each controller to automatically set its route prefix based on the class name. When the `Endpoint` class is included in each controller, the `prefix` option is set to the class name in lowercase. This prefix is then retrieved from each controller in the `map(e.prefix) { run(e.new) }` line.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a very simple example here:

Create a file `controller.rb`

```
get '/pages' do
  @pages = Pages.all
  erb :pages
end
```

Next create a `views` directory in the same folder as teh controller, and create a file named `pages.html.erb`

This is the corresponding view to your previously created controller action.

Here, you can type something like:

```
<% @pages.each do |p| %>
<%= p.title %>
<% end %>
```

Restart your server, visit `localhost:PORT/pages` and you will see a list of all your page titles.

You can check out this link for a simple sinatra tutorial - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/singing-with-sinatra--net-18965

Comment: why would empty controller.rb have `get()` available to it ?

Comment: As the link I posted suggests, you would have to include `gem 'sinatra'` in your controller

Answer (score 0):

You can make this as complicated or as simple as you need. For example:

Rails makes a lot of magic happen under the hood, whereas Sinatra is more flexible at the cost of requiring you to implement some of this stuff yourself.

```
controller_map = {
  'pages' => PagesController
}

post '/:controller/new' do
  c = params[:controller]
  module = controller_map[c]
  module.create_new()
  ...
end

get '/:controller/:id/show' do
  c = params[:controller]
  id = params[:id]
  module = controller_map[c]
  module.get(id)
  ...
end
```

Comment: What are the advantages of doing it that way instead of declaring them in `config.ru` via `map { MyController }` ?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you declare it, the example is for demonstrative purposes.