# MVC pattern for sinatra frame work

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I want to start coding with 'Sinatra' framework but i cant find a 'MVC' pattern  for this framework .
Is an 'MVC-Sinatra' pattern or framework?

Comment: Sinatra's really light and thin, it's great for quick things that don't need a lot of overhead. If you need something more than that, Rails can be stripped down to the basics and provides a very capable MVC environment.

Comment: ...And it you're not a Rails guy please consider [Hanami](http://hanamirb.org/). Also, if you want to understand the concepts behind [Rack](http://rack.github.io/) and improve a lot your ruby knowledge, please consider this other super lightweight alternatives: [Cuba](http://cuba.is/) and [Roda](http://roda.jeremyevans.net/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sinatra is a lightweight library, that aims to stay out of your way, leaving the door open for you to include or create what you need per project.

That said, you can create your own MVC on top of Sinatra rather easily, and incorporate ActiveRecord, DataMapper, Sequel, etc... for your Models. Here's a sample structure -

```
├── Gemfile
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── controllers
│   │   └── application_controller.rb
│   ├── models
│   │   └── model.rb
│   └── views
│       └── index.erb
├── config
│   └── environment.rb
├── config.ru
├── public
│   └── stylesheets
└── spec
    ├── controllers
    ├── features
    ├── models
    └── spec_helper.rb
```

**Gemfile** - where all your gems go.

**App Directory** - folder for MVC directories - models, views, and controllers.

**Models Directory** - holds the logic behind your application.

**Controllers Directory** - where the application configurations, routes, and controller actions are implemented.

**Views Directory** - holds the code that will be displayed in the browser.

**config.ru** - the `config.ru` file is necessary when building Rack-based applications and using rackup/shotgun to start the application server (the ru stands for `rackup`).

**Config Directory** - w/ `environment.rb` fileto connect up all the files in your application to the appropriate gems and to each other.

**Public Directory** - holds your front-end assets - CSS / JS / Images, etc...

**Spec Directory** - contains any tests for your applications.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check out [Padrino](http://padrinorb.com)

This is a framework built around Sinatra that provides a more "Rails like" feel to your project, but without as much hidden magic. It is a great example of what can be done with Sinatra.

Whilst this is great if you need to just get going, I would personally recommend that you use it as a learning tool to build your own apps using Sinatra in the way that makes the most sense to you. Write some tests / expectations, write some code, pass the tests - repeat :)

As for the ORM, you should also checkout [Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) which (imho) is very straight forward yet very flexible and powerful.

Comment: Sequel is great. Highly recommended if you can't use Active Record or want something more versatile.

Comment: I can second Padrino. I started building a simple Posts app to get to know it: https://github.com/Yorkshireman/padrino_blog It's like using something between Rails and Sinatra - it's quite a nice balance.

Answer (score 3):

Sinatra is simple enough that you can fit the models and controllers in one file.

See [here](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/models/data_mapper) for a very brief guide for how to do it.

To summarize some points,

- connect to database and write models. you can use datamapper, activerecord, etc for this. In my experience datamapper is nice because you don't need to write migrations. but activerecord has a better query interface.
- write controller actions / routes
- write views in the /views directory. assets go in the /public directory. /views/layout.erb can be used as a layout if it contains `<%= yield %>`

Comment: For an idea as to how to use individual rack-mounted Sinatra classes as controllers for a larger Sinatra-based application: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421971/how-to-map-routes-to-controllers-in-sinatra/30470141#30470141